# API - To upload image and to list them

Tags: php, image, api, file-upload, cloud-storage

I want to upload image to a image hosting service (free). I want users to upload images using the form in my website, but directly to the my image hosting's account(in a album). I don't want users to upload images to my server first and then later upload this file to imagehosting account by using my server script.

I have read about Imageshack's API and imgur API. But i donot think they will allow direct uploading.

Do you know any image hosting service or API, that allows:

- uploading images directly to the image hosting account (by users of
  my website, instead of using script to do the upload)
- easy to use API with PHP
- allows fetching of images from the albums later

Please help

Comment: Do you have database available? Like MySQL or something?

Comment: yes. but iam on a shared hosting. So, bigger image files can cause disk space consumption problem.

Comment: the free services wants to promote their product, I am afraid if there are any free hosting services like that (atleast not even asking to add their logo)

Comment: I am not against publishing their logo. This is for a non-commercial site. That is for a photo contest.

Comment: You could use XMLHttpRequest to POST an image to imagehack via javascript, then POST the returned image URL to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use uploadify library. This is very nice and usefull lib.

```
http://www.uploadify.com/
```